# How to draw path with d3.js correctly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

if you drag the red circle, it will move and black curved line will appear. But if try to move all around circle, line behaviour will be invalid.

I want to draw line all around green circle. Depends on mouse movements line should be more long or more short.
Please help me to write correct function.

my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/alexcat/q7qyaxqb/

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');
var startAngle = randomInteger(0, 120);

makeDraggable();

function makeDraggable () {
 var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", circleMoving);
 d3.select("#circle1").call(drag);
}

function circleMoving () {
                    var coords = d3.mouse(this);
                    var coordX = coords[0];
                    var coordY = coords[1];

                    var mainSheduleX = 300;
                    var mainSheduleY = 300;
                    var mainSheduleRadius = 150;

                    var hypotenuse = Math.sqrt((coordX - mainSheduleX) * (coordX - mainSheduleX) + (coordY - mainSheduleY) * (coordY - mainSheduleY));

                    var cosf = (coordX - mainSheduleX) / hypotenuse;
                    var sinf = (coordY - mainSheduleY) / hypotenuse;

                    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .on("drag", circleMoving);

                    var newX = mainSheduleRadius * cosf + parseInt(mainSheduleX);
                    var newY = (mainSheduleRadius * sinf + parseInt(mainSheduleY));

                    d3.select(this)
                        .attr('cx', newX)
                        .attr('cy', newY);

                    var angle = Math.atan2(newY - mainSheduleY, newX - mainSheduleX) + Math.PI / 2;

                    drawArcs(angle);
}

function drawArcs(endAngle) {
            d3.select("#line").remove();

var node = svg.node();
            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(150-5)
                .outerRadius(150)
                .startAngle(startAngle * (Math.PI / 180)) //converting from degs to radians
                .endAngle(endAngle); //just radians

            svg  
                .append("path")
                .attr("id", "line")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + node.clientWidth / 2 + "," + node.clientHeight / 2 + ")");
        }
        
function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="600">
  <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="150" fill="green"></circle>
  <circle id="circle1" cx="450" cy="300" r="20" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: what is the desired behavior then?

Comment: If you just want the arc to go all the way around, you can adjust the endAngle like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dk4n7kmc/. Though I'm not really sure that's what you're after.

Comment: Hi,
I want to draw line all around green circle. Depends on mouse movements line should be more long or more short.

Comment: user3432422, thanks for answer, but if i move mouse back, black line fill all green circle radius. Can you fix this, please?

Comment: user3432422, I mean you solution works only if start angle is 0, but I want to set random start angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user3432422, I realized correct condition (updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/alexcat/q7qyaxqb/8/).

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');

makeDraggable();

function makeDraggable () {
 var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", circleMoving);
 d3.select("#circle1").call(drag);
}

function circleMoving () {
                    var coords = d3.mouse(this);
                    var coordX = coords[0];
                    var coordY = coords[1];

                    var mainSheduleX = 300;
                    var mainSheduleY = 300;
                    var mainSheduleRadius = 150;

                    var hypotenuse = Math.sqrt((coordX - mainSheduleX) * (coordX - mainSheduleX) + (coordY - mainSheduleY) * (coordY - mainSheduleY));

                    var cosf = (coordX - mainSheduleX) / hypotenuse;
                    var sinf = (coordY - mainSheduleY) / hypotenuse;

                    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .on("drag", circleMoving);

                    var newX = mainSheduleRadius * cosf + parseInt(mainSheduleX);
                    var newY = (mainSheduleRadius * sinf + parseInt(mainSheduleY));

                    d3.select(this)
                        .attr('cx', newX)
                        .attr('cy', newY);

                    var startAngle = 60 * (Math.PI / 180);
                    var endAngle = Math.atan2(newY - mainSheduleY, newX - mainSheduleX) + Math.PI / 2;
                    
                    if (endAngle < startAngle) {
                        endAngle += 2 * Math.PI;
                    }

                    drawArcs(startAngle, endAngle);
}

function drawArcs(startAngle, endAngle) {
            d3.select("#line").remove();

var node = svg.node();
            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(150-5)
                .outerRadius(150)
                .startAngle(startAngle) //converting from degs to radians
                .endAngle(endAngle); //just radians

            svg  
                .append("path")
                .attr("id", "line")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + node.clientWidth / 2 + "," + node.clientHeight / 2 + ")");
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="600" height="600">
  <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="150" fill="green"></circle>
  <circle id="circle1" cx="450" cy="300" r="20" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```